# External Data on Communities using Site.com

Tags: site.com

Is it possible to expose external data from an external source to a community using Site.com builder? Are SOAP/REST calls possible within Site.com Community?

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Not sure about Site.com builder but I make tons of web calls on my custom build Site. Are you just looking for the functionality in the native Site.com Builder?

Comment: Hi @cricketlang When you said custom build site? Do you mean built using visualforce page?

yup, I was referring to the Site.com builder which doesn't use custom visualforce pages.

Comment: Yep. Our entire community is custom build and we use stub data in Salesforce to essentially make external web calls all over the place to get data from external systems and bring it back into the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your input @cricketlang. might stick to full custom built site instead of using site.com builder due to its limitations.

Comment: Just grab a bootstrap template or something of the sort. Usually the fastest way to whip something custom up.